# I'm Having Trouble Skipping Certain Characters from an Input Text File (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io, input, io

(I apologize that this is so low level compared to most of the questions I have seen on this website, but I have run out of ideas and I do not know who else to ask.)

I am working on a school project that requires me to read basketball statistics from a file named in06.txt. The file in06.txt looks exactly as follows:

5

P 17 24 9 31 28

R 4 5 1 10 7

A 9 2 3 6 8

S 3 4 0 5 4

I am required to read and store the first number, 5, into a variable called "games." From there, I must read the numbers from the second line and determine the high, the low, and the average. I must do the same thing for lines 3, 4, and 5. (FYI, the letters P, R, A, and S are there to indicate "Points," "Rebounds," "Assists," and "Steals.")

Since I only have been learning about programming for a few weeks, I do not want to overwhelm myself by jumping right into dealing with every aspect of the project. So, I am first working on determining the average from each line. My plan is to keep a running total of each line and then divide the running total by the number of games, which is 5 in this case.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int games;
    int points_high, points_low, points_total;
    int rebounds_high, rebounds_low, rebounds_total;
    int assists_high, assists_low, assists_total;
    int steals_high, steals_low, steals_total;
    double points_average, rebounds_average, assists_average, steals_average;

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("in06.txt");
        if( fin.fail() ) {
            cout << "\nInput file opening failed.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            cout << "\nInput file was read successfully.\n";

    int tempint1, tempint2, tempint3, tempint4;
    char tempchar;

    fin >> games;
    fin.get(tempchar);  // Takes the endl; from the text file.
    fin.get(tempchar);  // Takes the character P from the text file.

    while( fin >> tempint1 ) {
         points_total += tempint1;
    }

    fin.get(tempchar);  // Takes the endl; from the text file.
    fin.get(tempchar);  // Takes the character R from the text file.

    while( fin >> tempint2 ) {
        rebounds_total += tempint2;
    }

    fin.get(tempchar);  // Takes the endl; from the text file.
    fin.get(tempchar);  // Takes the character A from the text file.

    while( fin >> tempint3 ) {
         assists_total += tempint3;
    }

    fin.get(tempchar);   // Takes the endl; from the text file.
    fin.get(tempchar);   // Takes the character S from the text file.

    while( fin >> tempint4 ) {
         steals_total += tempint4;
    }

    cout << "The total number of games is " << games << endl;
    cout << "The value of total points is " << points_total << endl;
    cout << "The value of total rebounds is " << rebounds_total << endl;
    cout << "The value of total assists is " << assists_total << endl;
    cout << "The value of total steals is " << steals_total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the (incorrect) output:

```
Input file was read successfully.
The total number of games is 5
The value of total points is 111
The value of total rebounds is 134522076
The value of total assists is 134515888
The value of total steals is 673677934
```

I have been reading about file input in my textbook for hours, hoping that I will find something that will indicate why my program is outputting the incorrect values. However, I have found nothing. I have also researched similar problems on this forum as well as other forums, but the solutions use methods that I have not yet learned about and thus, my teacher would not allow them in my project code. Some of the methods I saw were arrays and the getline function. We have not yet learned about either.

Note: My teacher does not want us to store every integer from the input file. He wants us to open the file a single time and store the number of games, and then use loops and if statements for determining the high, average, and low numbers from each line.

If anyone could help me out, I would GREATLY appreciate it!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to narrow the problem down a litte?

Comment: Code!!! I you're applying [tag:c++], we want to see code!!

Comment: I did use a debugger. It returned no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have all these variables declared:

```
    int games;
    int points_high, points_low, points_total;
int rebounds_high, rebounds_low, rebounds_total;
int assists_high, assists_low, assists_total;
int steals_high, steals_low, steals_total;
double points_average, rebounds_average, assists_average, steals_average;
```

And then you increment them:

```
 points_total += tempint1;
```

Those variables were never initialzed to a known value (0), so they have garbage in them.  You need to initialize them.

Comment: I initialized points_total, rebounds_total, assists_total, and steals_total all to 0, and now my output says that the number of games is 5, the value of total points is 109, and the value of the other 3 are all 0.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what OldProgrammer said, you've approached the reading of integers incorrectly. A loop like this

```
while( fin >> tempint2 ) {
        rebounds_total += tempint2;
}
```

will stop when an error occurs. That is, either it reaches EOF or the extraction encounters data that cannot be formatted as an integer - or in other words, `good()` returns `false`. It *does not*, as you seem to think, stop reading at the end of a line. Once an error flag is set, all further extractions will fail until you clear the flags. In your case, a loop starts reading after `P`, extracts five intergers, but then it encounters the `R` from the next line and errors out.

Change this to a loop that reads a fixed number of integers or alternatively, read a whole line using `std::getline` into a `std::string`, put it into a `std::stringstream` and read from there.

In any case, learn to write robust code. *Check for success* of extractions and count how many elements you get.

An example of a loop that reads at most 5 integers:

```
int i;
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 5 && file >> i) {
    ++counter;
    // do something with i
}
if (counter < 5) {
    // hm, got less than 5 ints...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, my teacher has not yet taught us about strings or getline, so I am not allowed to use either one in my project code. We also have not learned about checking for success of extractions.

Comment: @user3398892 Checking for success of an extraction means checking the state of the stream *after* you tried the extraction. You're already doing this in `while (fin >> i)`. The expression `fin >> i` returns a reference to `fin` that's implicitly convertible to `bool`. It converts to `true` if stream is OK and `false` otherwise. You can also do this in an `if` statement - either by putting the extraction as the condition or by checking what `fail()` returns. I added an example loop in the answer.